# Error when using file:// URL in <a> tag in Vue.js - "Security Error: Content at ... may not load or link to ..."

Tags: html, vue.js, url, anchor

I have a Vue.js component which contains HTML as below:

```html
<a
  href="file://server1/english/cde/das%202.0/book.htm"
  target="_blank"
>
  Book
</a>
```

But when it renders, the link cannot be opened. And I see there was a warning in the browser console:

> Security Error: Content at http://server1:9999/book may not load or link to file:///server1/english/cde/das%202.0/book.htm.

I googled but have not found the solution to fix this. Seems it's a security risk to access the file using `file://` instead of `http://`.

This is an internal website, so can anyone help me silence/ ignore the security check?

Comment: Add code to allow user to upload file, then access it via http.

Comment: Hi @Tim, I did not mean that way. The file is already on a public shared server and can be accessed directly in browser using the href file:// url.